# How to display blob image from database in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, file-upload, blob

I am working on an e-commerce website and I created a form where I can upload product images to Mongodb database, I know there are several questions on the same topic however none of them have actually solved my problem, here is the code for uploading images :

```
const CreateProduct = () => {
const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        title:"",
        imageURL: [],
        desc: '',
        size: [],
        color: [],
        price: 0,
        category: [],
        collections: []
    });
const [imageURLS, setImageURLS] = useState([])
const [images, setImages] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
        if (images.length < 1) return;
        const newImageURLS = []
        images.forEach((image) => newImageURLS.push(URL.createObjectURL(image)))
        setImageURLS(newImageURLS)
    },[images])
    
    useEffect(() => {
        setFormData({ ...formData, imageURL: imageURLS })
    }, [imageURLS])

    const onImageChange = (e) => {
        setImages([...e.target.files])
    }

  {/**Image Upload */}
          <div className="flex flex-col p-20 justify-center items-center outline-dotted outline-[#1475cf] rounded">
            <input
              onChange={onImageChange}
              type='file'
              multiple
              accept="image/*"
              required
              className='text-sm text-gray-500 p-12 cursor-pointer'
            />  
            <div className="flex gap-x-6">
              {imageURLS.map((imageSrc) => (
                <div className="flex flex-row gap-x-4">
                <Image src={imageSrc} key={imageSrc} alt="product-image" width={200} height=.     {350} className="object-contain" />
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>

          </div>
}
```

This code is working perfectly but i am showing you this just for you to see the logic behind the image upload component, but when i save an image it saves it in this format blob:http://localhost:3000/50b8375b-6758-4d66-8c3e-be44a99d and i have been unable to display the images on react, here is the code i used for the frontend:

```
<Link href={`/products/${product._id}`} className='flex cursor-pointer flex-col'> 
                <Image 
                    src={URL.createObjectURL(product.imageURL[0])}
                    width={300}
                    height={470} 
                    alt='product image' 
                    //onMouseEnter={changeBackground} 
                    className='w-80 h-96'
                    placeholder='blur'
                />
```

i have tried different solution and everything i can think of but it's not working. Im getting this error when i used this: **Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': Overload resolution failed.**

I would really appreciate it if someone could reply to me as soon as possible.